# Capture notifications from other applications

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'm trying to capture the notifications from the other apps and display the text in a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) if possible.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/capture-toast-or-notification-using-accessibility-service/) and [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) shows `Receiver registered` when a notification arrives..

How can I read the content of notification?

I can intercept it with the service but I want display the content like `"Hi, how are you?"` in my TextView, is it possible?

I have added the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Are the other apps developed by you or you don't have any control over it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See notification of other app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279698/see-notification-of-other-app)