# See notification of other app

Tags: android, android-notifications

What API I should use for my app to see if I've received a notification from example from facebook, and so write in one textbox "Facebook!"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your best bet is to use  [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html), which was added in API level 18.

Here's an example:

```
public class FacebookNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        final String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName) && packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana")) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        // Nothing to do
    }

}
```

**In your AndroidManifest**

```
<service
    android:name="your.path.to.FacebookNotificationListener"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Also, your users will need to enable your app to listen for notifications to be posted under:

- Settings --> Security --> Notification access

But you can direct your users straight there by using the following `Intent`:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

Comment: Perfect It's all that I need! Thx! Only one thing when I call 'startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));'  I don't see the name of my app, what I made wrong?

Comment: @malloc Just make sure you've added the `Service` to your `AndroidManifest` and it includes the `BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission.

Comment: Is it possible to programmatically assign such authority? I create my own Launcher and would like to have access to notifications at once (the launcher will be in the sys- tem folder)